# How to get smooth curved graph using core Plot?

Tags: ios, objective-c, graph, core-plot

The graph is designed using core plot as shown.

[image]
My scatter plot code

```
CPTScatterPlot *editableLinePlot = [[CPTScatterPlot alloc] init];
editableLinePlot.interpolation = CPTScatterPlotInterpolationCurved;



CPTMutableLineStyle *lineStyle = [editableLinePlot.dataLineStyle mutableCopy];
lineStyle.lineWidth              = 3.0;
lineStyle.lineColor              = [CPTColor redColor];


editableLinePlot.dataLineStyle = lineStyle;
editableLinePlot.dataSource = self;
editableLinePlot.delegate = self;
editableLinePlot.identifier = redPlotIdentifier;
editableLinePlot.plotSymbolMarginForHitDetection = 20.0;
```

Plot Space is set as

```
/*Set scatter plot space and range*/
CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *)graph.defaultPlotSpace;
plotSpace.allowsUserInteraction = YES;
plotSpace.delegate              = self;
plotSpace.xScaleType = CPTScaleTypeLog;

plotSpace.yScaleType = CPTScaleTypeLinear;
/* Auto scale the plot space to fit the plot data*/
[plotSpace scaleToFitPlots:[graph allPlots]];
```

But when I move a plot point up or down , its not a smooth curve but instead shows as a small spike.
Did I miss out any implementation here.Please help, this problem is show stopper for me now.

Answer (score 0):

There are so many plot points on that graph that the plot symbols overlap. You are seeing a curved plot, it's just that the curve is so sharp around the points not on the baseline that they look like spikes.

Comment: Yes, I have to plot 666 points. Is there any way to set the Bezier range in core plot. So that I can apply bezier on some wider range. then the curve may not be like spikes.

Comment: Release 2.1 adds the `curvedInterpolationOption` to give some different ways to draw a curved plot line. The points on either side of the peaks are so close together that you'll see spikes no matter what curve method you use.  You'll need to remove some of the redundant points on the baseline to leave room for wider peaks.